# Decode Base64 string to PDF File Django Python?

Tags: python, django, pdf, base64, decode

I have this problem, I have this string in base 64:

`eC1hbXotaWQtMjogRW1VZWtRZHhLTWViUWZQa0txT...`

My idea is to decode the string and download the file (pdf), but when I try to download the file I have this screen

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIQ2Z.png)

I do not what happen, this is the code that I use to decode and download the file:

```
@login_required
def get_pdf_document_invoice(request, id):
    import base64
    print('invoice_pdf')
    customer = request.user.company.customer
    invoice_pdf = customer.get_pdf_invoice(id)
    contentb64 = invoice_pdf['data']
    decode_file = base64.b64decode(contentb64)
    print(invoice_pdf, "pdf")
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=invoice.pdf'
    response.write(decode_file)
    return response
```